# why can't I add the same panel to a flow layout panel at run time in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I've tried adding the same panel to a flowlayout panel at runtime and doesn't seem to work , but when I add a different panel it seems to work just fine
Why is that ?
Why can't I add the same panel more than once ?

Comment: Because just like you and me, a panel can't exist in two places at once. Create a copy of it with all its child controls. Or better, add the child controls to a UserControl at design-time and then create multiple instances of that UserControl at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the same panel type twice, but not the same panel instance. This is because each control must be able to store its own set of properties. Especially their `Location` and `Size`, but also the tab order and z-index and so on. Controls like text boxes must be able to have different `Text` values.

```
var c = new MyUserControl();
flowLayout1.Controls.Add(c); 
flowLayout1.Controls.Add(c); // Does not work as expected.
```

but

```
flowLayout1.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl()); 
flowLayout1.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl()); // Adds a second control as expected.
```